# I wanted to show the pre-select value v-autocomplete component of vuetify.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working with the vue.js and vuetify.js and i want to show the pre-select value in v-autocomplete like we do in dropdown when editing any records.

Is there any way to do that in v-autocomplete ?

I have tried assigning model:

```
                        <v-autocomplete 
                            v-model="tlData.countryId" 
                            label="select country*" 
                            :items='countries'
                            @change="getCountryCode()" 
                            required>
                        </v-autocomplete>
```

i have assigned

> tlData.countryId = response.data.id

but this is not working for me.

Comment: please share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: I am using v-model="editTlData.countryId" property to preselect the value but this is not working for me.

Comment: please edit your question with more details

Comment: use `Vue.set` if you randomly add properties to objects. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: i am trying to do something like this: <option value="10" selected>10</select> with v-autocomplete if you are getting my point.

Comment: You can use use auto-select-first but then you have to change the order of the elements. Probably it is better to use the v-select in combination with a filter (property/method)

Comment: No answer still?